# ngrok - how to create a link which has /___ after it

Tags: server, localhost, ngrok

I am looking to use ngrok to host my local server to show a colleague.

My issue is that my server URL is like so `http://localhost:8080/viewer/`

I've tried `ngrok http 8080/viewer` but that is throwing an error `ERROR:  Tunnel 'command_line' specifies an invalid or malformed address '8080/viewer': strange hostname`

How can I host my server correctly using ngrok?

Comment: You can simply run your ngrok instance on your 8080 port on localhost and then navigate to the `viewer` url: i.e...`ngrok http -host-header="localhost:[port]" [port]`

Answer (score 0):

PM from ngrok here. to share your local service running on `http://localhost:8080/viewer/`, just use the hostname, not the path, in your ngrok command. You can just run `ngrok http 8080` and then replace `http://localhost:8080` in your url with the domain ngrok provides, and append the `/viewer/` path. So it will look something like `https://[random-string].ngrok-free.app/viewer/`.

As the other commenter mentioned, you can also append `--host-header rewrite` to your ngrok command if your app is expecting the host header to be modified. You can find more details in the [ngrok docs](https://ngrok.com/docs/secure-tunnels/tunnels/http-tunnels/#host-header).